# Get joined datas during a MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

## My environment:

I have these tables:

Table `___Billing`:

```
|----------|----------|----------|--------------|---------------------|
| BIL_Id   | BIL_Item | BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_ApplicableTaxes |
|----------|----------|----------|--------------|---------------------|
| 1        | Hot-Dog  | 4.50     | 2            | 3                   |
| 2        | Tea      | 3.25     | 3            | 3,4                 |
|----------|----------|----------|--------------|---------------------|
```

`BIL_Id` = the ID for this item in this table.
`BIL_Item` = the id of the item (referring to the ___SalesTaxes table).
`BIL_Quantity` = the quantity of the item the customer used.
`BIL_ApplicableTaxes` = the id of the applicable taxes for this item. Each taxe id is comma separated.

---

Table `___SalesTaxes`:

```
|----------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id   | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|----------|--------------|------------|
| 3        | Tax 1        | 3.50       |
| 4        | Tax 2        | 6.55       |
|----------|--------------|------------|
```

`STX_Id` = the ID for this item in this table.
`STX_TaxeName` = the name of the taxe.
`STX_Amount` = the amount in percentage of the taxe.

---

## My question:

How is it possible from these two tables, to loop into the `___Billing` table in order to get the taxes in percentage I need to applied ?

For example :

- For the first row, I should have: `3.50`.
- For the second row, I should have : `3.50, 6.55`.

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you phrase your query correctly, you can use MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET()` function to match tax IDs agains the CSV list you have in the `BIL_ApplicableTaxes` column:

```
SELECT t1.BIL_Id,
       t1.BIL_Rate,
       GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.STX_Amount, 'NA')) AS tax_due
FROM ___Billing t1
LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.STX_Id, t1.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
GROUP BY t1.BIL_Id
```

However, you should seriously consider normalizing the `___Billing` table and removing the CSV data.  Instead, each tax entry should have its own record.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question. Can I begin the query by the `___Billing` table or I need to begin by the `___SalesTaxes` one ?

Comment: @user7347588 Yes, you can, I updated with your suggestion.